# Adding ending </tr> tags to an HTML strings within loop

Tags: javascript, html

I have an array of elements I would like to put into an HTML table:

```
var tags_arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19];
```

I can make an HTML table by simply placing beginning `<tr>` tags every 4th iteration:

```
var checks = "<table border=1>";

for (var c = 0; c < tags_arr.length; c++){



    if (c%4 == 0){

         checks += "<tr>";

    }

    checks += "<td>" + tags_arr[c] + "</td>";

}

checks += "</table>";
$("body").append(checks);
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/OPOCOBum/1/)

However this solution relies on the browser to inject the closing `<\tr>` tag when it "sees" the new opening tag. The browser also seems not to care that the last row has fewer `<td>` cells than the previous rows do.

It works, but is there a way to make expand this so as not to completely rely on the browser. I've tried using a regex to inject them into the string, but it seems like there should be a way to do so in the loop. Is it feasible? Or since it only has to work in modern browsers, can I just rely on Chrome and Firefox to do the cleanup for me?

**EDIT:**

hacky regex way:

```
checks = checks.replace(/(<tr>)/g, "</tr><tr>").replace(/<\/tr>/, "");

checks += "</tr></table>";
```

Comment: You don't need to worry about it.  You don't really need closing `<td>` or `<tr>` tags in an HTML5 document. (You do need a closing `<table>` or else it'll think the rest of the page is part of the last `<td>`).

Comment: This may be true, but it assumes that the page being rendered is HTML5 and is declared as such - and the four answers given at the time of this comment all solve the problem so that the document is complete.

Comment: @RobBaillie true, though HTML5 has as a starting point de facto standard browser behavior. I acknowledge that it *might* be possible to confuse a browser by doing this in a strict XHTML context. (I'm also not sure why anybody would be making new pages that aren't HTML5 pages, but I'm a rebel.)

Comment: Check out [all the sample tables](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) in the HTML5 spec for further reference. I've stumbled across the part of the spec that describes when closing tags can be skipped, but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: Ah [here it is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) - towards the end of that list.

Comment: @Pointy Due to the very last question in my post I think your first comment is the best, shortest, and most easily implemented solution. Will you submit it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML5 spec [explicitly](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) tells us that it's not necessary to close `<tr>` and `<td>` tags in the obvious scenarios:

- No need to close a `<td>` before the next `<td>` or `<tr>` or table block section (`<tbody>`, `<tfoot>`), or the `</table>` closing tag.
- No need to close a `<tr>` before the next `<tr>`, block section, or table close.

I seriously doubt you'll run into modern browsers that won't do the right thing here. I bet even IE6 will do it properly.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much once more!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply append the TR closing tag before appending the starting TR tag:

```
for (var c = 0; c < tags_arr.length; c++){
    if (c%4 == 0){
         if (c !== 0) checks +="</tr>";
         checks += "<tr>";
    }
    checks += "<td>" + tags_arr[c] + "</td>";
}

checks += "</tr></table>";
```

PS: Take care of the edge cases.

EDIT:
A more elgant solution is to distribute the items in arrays before hand:

```
var distributed = [];
var tags_arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19];
while(tags_arr.length > 0) {
  distributed.push(tags_arr.splice(0,4));
}
```

And then use some smart loops to create the html:

```
var html = distributed.reduce(function(html, item){ 
  var td = item.reduce(function(html, item){
    return html + '<td>' + item + '</td>';
  }, '');
  return html + '<tr>' + td + '</tr>';
}, '');

html = '<table border=1>' + html + '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just close the tr tag before opening one. If c == 0 no tag have been opened yet.
Don't forget to close the last  tag after the for loop

```
var checks = "<table border=1>";

for (var c = 0; c < tags_arr.length; c++){



    if (c%4 == 0){
         if (c > 0)
            checks += "</tr>"
         checks += "<tr>";

    }

    checks += "<td>" + tags_arr[c] + "</td>";

}
if (tags_arr.length > 0)
    checks += "</tr>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var c = 0; c < tags_arr.length; c++){
    if (c%4 == 0){
        if (c > 0) {
            checks += "</tr>";
        }
        checks += "<tr>";
    }
    checks += "<td>" + tags_arr[c] + "</td>";
}
if (c > 0) { // Don't add a closing tag if there were no rows at all
    checks += "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var cell = 0, len = tags_arr.length;
for(var row = 0; cell < len; row++) {
    checks += '<tr>';
    for(var col = 0; col < 4 && cell < len; col++, cell++)
        checks += '<td>' + tags_arr[cell] + '</td>'; 
    checks += '</tr>';
}
```

The correct solution - no divisions, no exceptional cases, no extra memory.